# populate textboxes after selecting combobox value

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, textbox

I have searched and could not quite find the right answer. I have a combobox that you select a value, then i would like it to "fetch" the remainer of the record and display it in textboxs.

Here is my current code. not sure where to go from here.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Combo</title>
<meta name="generator" content="90 Second Website Builder 10 - http://www.90secondwebsitebuilder.com">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="combo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="combo.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.90secondwebsitebuilder.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/builtwithwwb10.png" alt="90 Second Website Builder" style="position:absolute;left:441px;top:967px;border-width:0;z-index:250"></a>
<?php
    $cn=mysql_connect("localhost","Username","password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("DBname",$cn) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblLoads ORDER BY LoadNumber DESC;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<select name="Loads" size=1 style="position:absolute;left:133px;top:10px;width:81px;height:22px;z-index:1;">

<?php
    while($ri = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<option value=" .$ri['LoadNumber'] . ">" . $ri['LoadNumber'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select> "
    /* I want to populate these boxes from DB after Combobox Selection
       Data comes from same table as the combobox values */
    <input type="text" id="ShipperName" name="ShipperName" value="" readonly>
    <input type="text" id="ShipperAddr" name="ShipperAddr" value="" readonly>
?>
</body>

</html>
```

The LoadNumber field is the primary key of the table. There will be only one record that corresponds to that LoadNumber. The two textboxs are the fieldnames in the table "shippername" and "shipperaddr".

Comment: User has to select from the select field, and when the user does, it will populate the data inside the two textboxes below? The data will also be coming from the your `tblLoads` table? What columns are they? And is your `LoadNumber` column the primary key of your `tblLoads` table? You are looking for javascript/Ajax for it.

Comment: You wanted your post to re-open but you don't respond to the answer and my comment. Please explain.

Comment: Your solution below solved the problem precisely. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Note:

- You can do it using javascript and Ajax.
- Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API.

Lets create a script using a javascript library called jQuery. Download it [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Lets assign first an `id` tag to your select input field.

```
<select id="loads" .....
```

Then the script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> <!-- REPLACE THE FILE DEPENDING ON THE JQUERY VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */

    $("#loads").change(function(){ /* TRIGGER THIS WHEN USER HAS SELECTED DATA FROM THE SELECT FIELD */

      var loadnumber = $(this).val(); /* STORE THE SELECTED LOAD NUMBER TO THIS VARIABLE */

      $.ajax({ /* START AJAX */

        type: "POST", /* METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "action.php", /* THE FILE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
        data: {"loadnumber": loadnumber}, /* THE DATA WE WILL PASS TO action.php */
        dataType: 'json', /* DATA TYPE THAT WILL BE RETURNED FROM action.php */
        success: function(result){
          /* PUT CORRESPONDING RETURNED DATA FROM action.php TO THESE TWO TEXTBOXES */
          $("#ShipperName").val(result.shippername);
          $("#ShipperAddr").val(result.shipperaddr);
        }

      }); /* END OF AJAX */   

    }); /* END OF CHANGE #loads */

  });

</script>
```

Then on your `action.php`, which will return the corresponding data depending on the selected load number from the form.

```
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST["loadnumber"])){

    /* RE-ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "Username", "password", "DBname");

    /* CHECK CONNECTION */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    /* PREPARE YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT shippername, shipperaddress FROM tblLoads WHERE LoadNumber = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST["loadnumber"]); /* PARAMETIZE THIS VARIABLE TO YOUR QUERY */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($shippername, $shipperaddress); /* BIND THE RESULTS TO THESE VARIABLES */
    $stmt->fetch(); /* FETCH THE RESULTS */
    $stmt->close(); /* CLOSE THE PREPARED STATEMENT */

    /* RETURN THIS DATA TO THE MAIN FILE */
    echo json_encode(array("shippername" => $shippername, "shipperaddr" => $shipperaddress));

  } /* END OF IF NOT EMPTY loadnumber */

?>
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks, that works terrific. One additional question if I may, The shipper contact information is in a seperate table, using the ShipperID key that I get from this query. Is it possible to run additional queries after this one to get additional information? Am i clear?

Comment: @Musicdad Yes. You can. You can do LEFT JOIN or a nested loop. If my answer did help you, you can give back by accepting or upvoting my answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: Logan, I got this to work on one page and its perfect, then I try and move it to a new page and modify it a little and it doesnt seem to work. How do I know that the combobox is firing the script?

Comment: @Musicdad Hit F12 on your browser. You might see errors on the console.

Comment: it shows my script is loading without any line feeds, so its basically on one line and i think thats why its not working. How do I break up the line. I have tried 3 different editors.

Comment: There is no error on the console log? Try running the action.php if there is an error.